# Easiest way to have an on-load Bootstrap popover using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the AngularJS Bootstrap Popover directive from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover .

I'd like to have the popover appear **both** when user hovers mouse over button **and** when the button is first shown (for about 3 seconds, then it disappears).

Possibly this could be done using `$tooltipProvider.setTriggers`, but what events I have to listen to, and whether I can have the tooltip invoked from both events (e.g., pass two values to `popover-trigger` attribute) I'm not sure on.

Is there a straightforward solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand completely your question, but the set trigger for the mouse Hover is "mouseenter", the opposite is the "blur" setting, on this you can set a fade away animation, maybe with the ngBlur attribute. to let the popover all ready open on load(if i understand your third need) the popover have an attribute named "isOpen" you have to set it true.

## EDIT

To have a full view on what you can or cannot do with the tooltip directives  open the ui-bootsrap.js file. Inside of it you'll find any type of parameters or attribute you can use, search isOpen inside the file, you'll find the method, it's all written very well and it's easy to understand the functioning. But for your purpose i suggest you to write a function with a timeout interval set to three second, that maybe change the popover ng-show from true to false after that laps of time, but first of all go to read the tooltip directive and after that you can easily resolve your problem.

Comment: I can do the `mouseenter` one fine; it works. It's the having it open on load for 3 seconds that I have an issue with.

I'm not sure how to set the `isOpen` from AngularJS. I don't see it documented in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover . Where is it documented?

Comment: I have edited the answer because it's to long for a comment, the only things that i want to say to you and to everyone, the documentation on github lack of some explanations, the better way to have a full knowing of these modules is to open the ui-bootstrap.js file.

Comment: Still not sure how to invoke the `isOpen`; binding to 'popover-is-open' doesn't seem to do anything; I tried extracting it out into an element directive invocation (hoping to then use `ng-show`) but that didn't do anything at all.